# SMSA Tracking status

Tags: opencart2.3

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache

$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://track.smsaexpress.com/SECOM/SMSAwebService.asmx?wsdl');

$auth_call2 = $soapClient->getTracking('290018583252','Testing0');

print_r($auth_call2); exit;

I am getting error as

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help me, to track SMSA in opencart php platform

Comment: Please check if you are passing correct parameter to getTracking() method. The error "Object reference..." usually appear if the code does not provide enough try catch to handle the exception.

Comment: try to add 'request', as shown in the above post